# different JSON output for the same Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to view FB post content in Graph API Explorer, the outputs are different using different id compositions:
1) input id just as post id: 300172370041643

The link is: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=300172370041643

The output JSON is:

```
{
  "id": "300172370041643", 
  "from": {
    "name": "YouThinkIAmFunny", 
    "category": "Comedian", 
    "id": "285144131496245"
  }, 
  "link": "http://www.nba.com/rockets/media/PODCAST_1.26.12_32K.mp3", 
  "name": "PODCAST 1.26.12 32K", 
  "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif", 
  "created_time": "2012-02-06T16:29:55+0000", 
  "type": "link"
}
```

2) input id as page id + post id: 285144131496245_300172370041643

The link is: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=285144131496245_300172370041643

The output JSON is:

```
{
  "id": "285144131496245_300172370041643", 
  "from": {
    "name": "YouThinkIAmFunny", 
    "category": "Comedian", 
    "id": "285144131496245"
  }, 
  "story": "YouThinkIAmFunny shared a link.", 
  "source": "http://www.nba.com/rockets/media/PODCAST_1.26.12_32K.mp3", 
  "name": "PODCAST 1.26.12 32K", 
  "caption": "www.nba.com", 
  "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/y0/r/nAApRnfWfNW.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/285144131496245/posts/300172370041643"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/285144131496245/posts/300172370041643"
    }
  ], 
  "type": "music", 
  "created_time": "2012-02-06T16:29:56+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-02-06T16:29:56+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Ananya Mstr", 
        "id": "100002161609091"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 1
  }, 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }, 
  "is_published": true
}
```

My question is they both belong to the same post in the same page, but why there is difference between the data returned? Especially the post type, the former one is 'link', but the latter one is 'music', why and how does FB mark this type field?
Can anyone give me a hint, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because the second path suggests that you want it in post context. So the returned structure is having all the additional information you could need to interact with the post - the actions part mostly.

As for why in the first case it is link and in the second source ("link": "http://www.nba.com/rockets/media/PODCAST_1.26.12_32K.mp3" vs "source": "http://www.nba.com/rockets/media/PODCAST_1.26.12_32K.mp3") it just looks like an inconsistency with the naming convention for different "objects" - the link itself and the link as a post.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems 300172370041643 and 285144131496245_300172370041643 have different meanings, am I correct?

Comment: That is what I think. Maybe somebody else can confirm it. Check the Facebook documentation about posts(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) and links (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/)